# how to append the table body by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to Append the tbody of table to already existing table how can i append the table.Actually I want to search the word from whole table .BY javascript and ajax.How can I append the table tbody in search.php page,please get me over this.
 search.php

```
   <div >
      <table id="table">
        <thead>
        <th>
        Email
        </th>
        <th>
        Firstname
        </th>
        <th>
        Lastname
        </th>
        <th>
        Companyname
        </th>
        <th>
        Title
        </th>
        <th>
        LinkedinURL
        </th>
        <th>
        Domain
        </th>
        <th>
        Companylocation
        </th>
        <th>
        Companysizecategory
        </th>
        <th>
       Companyfunding
        </th>
        <th>
        Companyindustry
        </th>
        <th>
        Companywebtech
        </th>
        <th>
        DateDownloaded
        </th>
        <th>
        ElucifyAccountID
        </th>
        </thead>


      </table>
      </div>
    </form>
      </div>
    </form>
      </body>
    </html>
    <script>
    $("#search").keyup(function()
    {
     var search=$(this).val();
     $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"searchajax.php",
         data:{
          ajaxsearch:search,
         },
         success:function(data){

          alert("success");
         },
         error:function(){
          alert('error');
         }

     });
    });
    </script>
```

ajax.php

```
if (!empty($_POST['ajaxsearch'])) 
{
       $search=$_POST['ajaxsearch'];
$sql="SELECT * from company";
$sql_query=mysql_query($sql);
$logicStr="WHERE ";
$count=mysql_num_fields($sql_query);
for($i=0 ; $i < mysql_num_fields($sql_query) ; $i++){
 if($i == ($count-1) )
$logicStr=$logicStr."".mysql_field_name($sql_query,$i)." LIKE '%".$search."%' ";
else
$logicStr=$logicStr."".mysql_field_name($sql_query,$i)." LIKE '%".$search."%' OR ";
}

$sql="SELECT * from company ".$logicStr;
//echo "SELECT * from company ".$logicStr;
$get=mysql_query($sql);

$i=0;
while($getresult=mysql_fetch_array($get))
  {

    echo '<tbody>';
    echo'<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
     echo $getresult['Email'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo'<td>';
     echo $getresult['Firstname'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
     echo $getresult['Lastname'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo'<td>';
     echo $getresult['Companyname'];
     echo '</td>';
    echo'<td>';
    echo $getresult['Title'];
    echo'</td>';
    echo'<td>';
     echo $getresult['LinkedinURL'];
     echo'</td>';
    echo '<td>';
     echo $getresult['Domain'];
     echo'</td>';
    echo'<td>';
     echo $getresult['CompanyLocation'];
     echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
     echo $getresult['Companysizecategory'];
     echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
     echo $getresult['Companyfunding']
     echo'</td>';
   echo'<td>';
    echo $getresult['Companyindustry'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
     echo $getresult['companywebtech'];
     echo'</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $getresult['Datedownloaded'];
    echo'</td>';
    echo '<td>';
     echo $getresult['ElucifyAccountID'];
     echo'</td>';
     echo'</tr>';
     echo'</tbody>';


   $i++;
   }
   } 
   else
   {
    echo'<script>window.alert("enter valid Data")</script>';
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated .try to use mysqli_*  prepared statement

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. But my doubt is how to append the tbody in ajax.php to search.php using ajax

Comment: $('#table thead').insertAfter(result);

Comment: I have tried this but no output

Comment: try my updated comment @arjun  $('#table thead').insertAfter(data);

Comment: I tried your comment@JYoThI already existing thead in search.php is disappeared

Comment: is there any mistake in Ajax.php@JYoThI

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"searchajax.php",
    data:{
        ajaxsearch:search,
    },
    success:function(data){
        $('#table thead').insertAfter(data);
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: i have tried this comment @Ankesh Vaishnav .already existing thead in search.php is disappeared

Answer (score 0):

In your `ajax.php`, you already print `<tbody>`. So if you want to append that ajax `<tbody>` to existing `search.php`, please try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"searchajax.php",
    data:{ajaxsearch:search},
    success:function(data){
        $('#table tbody').append(data);
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

> Note: if you use `append`, existing rows are not delete before append
>   new data. This may cause duplicate rows.

If you don't need duplicate rows, you can remove or empty `<tbody>` before append as shown in below.

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"searchajax.php",
        data:{ajaxsearch:search},
        success:function(data){
            $('#table tbody').empty();
            $('#table tbody').append(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```